# ArgoCD with kustomize to replace images during runtime

Tags: gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner, kustomize, argocd

We are trying to deploy few deployment files with `argocd app create` command. Our yaml file contains a parameter for specifying the image name dynamically. We are looking at passing the image value with argocd cli to replace this variable during runtime. Parameter overrides of argocd don't seem to work for non-helm deployments.
Below is the `deployment.yaml` file which hold the placeholders for the image:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: helloworld-gitlab
    image: '###IMAGE###'
```

`kustomization.yaml` is as below:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- gitlab_msd_deployment.yaml
- gitlab_msd_service.yaml
```

We are passing the below values in the argocd command.

```
argocd app create helloworld-gitlab --repo https://example.git --path ./k8s-deployments/  --dest-server https://kubernetes.default.svc --dest-namespace ${NAMESPACE} --kustomize-image $IMAGE
```

But the pod has `InvalidImageName` state with the error below:

```
Failed to apply default image tag "###IMAGE###": couldn't parse image reference "###IMAGE###": invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
```

Any idea how we can get the placeholder replaced with the value sent in the `argocd app create` command?
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I could get this working as below (with help from the slack channel). File definitions are [here](https://github.com/mayzhang2000/argocd-example-apps/blob/master/kustomize-guestbook/guestbook-ui-deployment.yaml#L17).

```
argocd app create mykustomize-guestbook --repo https://github.com/mayzhang2000/argocd-example-apps.git --path kustomize-guestbook --dest-namespace default --dest-server https://kubernetes.default.svc --kustomize-image myImage=gcr.io/heptio-images/ks-guestbook-demo:0.1
```